# How to solve Express error : TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I'm new to express and angular trying to build register and display registered users list. I'm using a function to register user and save data in mango db - executing successfully (i can see the registered users in mongo and works in postman). Now i want to retrieve all the registered users using another function api user but there is an error.

My code

```
const User = require('../models/user')

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body
    let user = new User(userData)
    
    user.save((error, registeredUser) => {
       if (error){
          console.log(error)
       }
       else 
       {
          let payload= { subject: registeredUser._id}
          let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secretkey')
          res.status(200).send({token}) 
       }
    })
})
```

retrieving user function

```
router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
   let users = User.find()
   res.json(users)
})
```

User Schema Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
   email: String,
   password: String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'Users')
```

--- error ---

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
|property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
|property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
--- property 'topology' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (
<anonymous>
)
```

Comment: Where does `JSON.stringify` come from? What is the line failing?

Comment: Im not using JSON.stringify anywhere in entire code

Comment: What is the line returning the error? There is nothing to tell you where is the code that was failing? also try to run this instead `router.get('/user',(req, res)=>{
  User.find({}, (error, users) => {
    if (error) return next(error);
    // or
    // if (error) throw error;
    res.json(users)
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

you're making a db call, which will be a async operation.so res.json(users) line won't wait for db response.

```
router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
 let users = User.find()
 res.json(users)
})
```

solution

```
router.get('/user', async (req, res) => {
 let users = await User.find({})
 res.json(users)
})
```